# How to order a list with Django's Paginator?

Tags: python, django, pagination

**Here we go:**

1. I have an object's list that I retrieve from my Database and I sort it by a field.
2. Then I paginates the result list, by getting an specific page.

**Problem:**
The result list is sorted by my field, but its done only by page, **NOT THE WHOLE LIST.**

Example:

[1,8,5,12,7,3]

I get:

- Page 01: [1,5,8]
- Page 02: [3,7,12]

But I want

- Page 01: [1,3,5]
- Page 02: [7,8,12]

Here is my code:

```
    queryset = Valorations.objects.filter(category_id__exact=cat).order_by('points')
    paginator = Paginator(queryset, 3)
    try:
        vals = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        vals = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        vals = []
    return vals
```

**I guess its somehting about Lazy Loading, how can I avoid it?**

Comment: I don't think your code should give that result -- maybe there's more to your code that you haven't shown. The question is a big confusing because your queryset has `order_by('-date_begin')` but your examples are integers in ascending order.

Comment: I guess its somehting about Lazy Loading ... I still cant figure out how to avoid this.

Comment: I still don't think your example is reproducible.